# Как в коде определить что свойство объекта является итерируемым?

Tags: c#

Хочу сделать *универсальный* метод выгружающий таблицу в pdf.

Набросок метод:

```
static PdfPTable printTable<T>(IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition> columns, IEnumerable<T> rows, Font font)
{
    var table = new PdfPTable(columns.Count());

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            var value = column.Property.GetValue(row, null);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(value as Enumerable);
            if (value is IEnumerable<DTO.StateReason> nestedRows)
            {
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(printTable(nestedRows.GetColumnDefinitions(), nestedRows, font)) { Padding = 0});
            }
            else
            {
                var textContent = string.Empty;
                if (value != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(column.Format))
                {
                    switch (column.TypeName)
                    {
                        case nameof(DateTime):
                            {
                                textContent = ((DateTime)value).ToString(column.Format);
                                break;
                            }
                        case nameof(Int16):
                        case nameof(Int32):
                        case nameof(Int64):
                            {
                                textContent = ((int)value).ToString(column.Format);
                                break;
                            }
                        case nameof(Decimal):
                            {
                                textContent = ((decimal)value).ToString(column.Format);
                                break;
                            }
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if(value != null)
                {
                    textContent = value.ToString();
                }
                table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(textContent, font)));
            }
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

реализация метода `GetColumnDefinition`

```
static IEnumerable<ColumnDefinition> GetColumnDefinitions<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    try
    {
        var index = 0;
        var result = (from property in typeof(T).GetProperties().OrderBy(x => x.Name)
                      let columnAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ColumnAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault() as ColumnAttribute
                      let formatAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayFormatAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault() as DisplayFormatAttribute
                      let ignoreAttribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(IgnoreAttribute), true).SingleOrDefault() as IgnoreAttribute
                      where ignoreAttribute == null
                      select new ColumnDefinition
                      {
                          Property = property,
                          Name = columnAttribute?.Name ?? property.Name,
                          TypeName = columnAttribute?.TypeName ?? string.Empty,
                          Format = formatAttribute?.DataFormatString ?? string.Empty,
                          Order = columnAttribute?.Order ?? index++
                      })
                      .OrderBy(x => x.Order);
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

пример классов для печати таблицы в pdf

```
public class ActHistoryList
{
    [Services.Exports.Ignore]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Services.Exports.Ignore]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    [Column("Состояние", Order = 0)]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public IList<StateReason> Reasons { get; set; } = new List<StateReason>();
    [Column("Дата/Время", Order = 2, TypeName = nameof(DateTime)), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    [Column("Автор", Order = 3)]
    public string Author { get; set; }
}

public class StateReason
{
    [Services.Exports.Ignore]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("Основание", Order = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column("Комментарий", Order = 2)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Код рабочий, не соображу как реализовать рекурсивный вызов если значение **value** является массивом, коллекций и т.п., В коде это `if(value is IEnumerable<DTO.StateReason> nestedRows)`, вместо `DTO.StateReason` может быть любой класс.

Comment: Просто IEnumerable используйте

Comment: Только имейте ввиду, что не все итерируемые объекты стоит итерировать. Например, `string`

Comment: @АндрейNOP очень хорошее замечание, может подскажите как обойти сей подводный камень?!

Comment: Когда-то сталкивался с подобным, проверял явно на `string`, типа `is IEnumerable && !is string`. "Красивого" решения не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если проблема заключается в том, что вместо DTO.StateReason может быть любой класс, то `IEnumerable<DTO.StateReason>` ты можешь заменить на `IEnumerable` и получить старый .NET 2.0 вариант с `object`'ами.

Если же интересует ответ на вопрос, то для того чтобы свойство было итерируемым, его тип должен реализовывать метод [`IEnumerator GetEnumerator();`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Соответственно, при помощи отражения (Reflection) ты можешь получить тип объекта ([`GetType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netframework-4.7.2)), и перечислить его методы ([`GetMethods`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods?view=netframework-4.7.2)) в поисках нужного. Или же проверить, что он реализует интерфейс `IEnumerable`: `typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType)`.

Так или иначе, попытки строить обобщённый код над Generic-ами - это всегда боль. По хорошему, стоит компилировать при помощи [Expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2) или [ILGenerator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator?view=netframework-4.7.2) лямбда-выражение и вызывать его, чтобы нивелировать издержки привносимые отражением.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, насколько сложно перевести пример уже написанного мной кода в `Expression`, я просто в них полный ноль

Comment: @Bald ты сперва на Reflection опиши, воспользуйся профилировщиком, возможно, в твоём случае это будет занимать доли секунды и не станет бутылочным горлышком.